# My website is vibrating on iPhone 14 and above devices

Tags: iphone, wordpress

While building my website, I noticed an issue - some pages are vibrating on iPhone 14 and above devices.

Example page: https://yenitema.serdenci.com/sevdigim-diziler/kurtlar-vadisi/

Initially, I thought it might be due to images on one page, and after some testing, it worked. However, the issue persists on another page. I even tried disabling the listing feature on one page, which worked, but it didn't solve the problem on another page. Instead of looking for individual solutions for each page, it would be more logical to identify the source of this problem. Interestingly, simulating iPhone 14 resolution in the browser does not replicate the vibration issue; it only occurs on the actual device. Can you assist me with this matter?